# WPF IsSelected prevent trigger when selecting child

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem I've ran into and I'm not sure if it is possible to prevent it. I supose it is designed like this by default.

I have coded a treeview list to be filled by a XML and each of these node, when selected, are filling some textbox. Depending on their type, it will trigger a different function.

The problem is that when I select a child, it seems to trigger "IsSelecting" for all parents treeviewitem all the way to the top which in return trigger the associated function as well and I don't want that.

Any idea how to prevent this "Sort of reverse inheritance" for IsSelected?

**Example (check with code below):** selecting a "node" will trigger "Node_Selected", "Dialog_Selected", "Actor_Selected".

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,

**Just for context:**

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load("XML/ActorsDialogs.xml");

        XmlNodeList actors = document.SelectNodes("/dialogs/actor");

        foreach (XmlNode actor in actors)
        {
            TreeViewItem newActor = new TreeViewItem();
            newActor.Header = actor.SelectSingleNode("actorname").InnerText;
            newActor.Selected += new RoutedEventHandler(Actor_Selected);

            XmlNodeList dialogs = actor.SelectNodes("dialog");
            foreach (XmlNode dialog in dialogs)
            {
                TreeViewItem newdialog = new TreeViewItem();
                newdialog.Header = "Dialog:" + dialog.SelectSingleNode("dialogID").InnerText;
                newdialog.Selected += new RoutedEventHandler(Dialog_Selected);

                BuildNodes(newdialog, dialog);

                newActor.Items.Add(newdialog);
            }
            ActorsList.Items.Add(newActor);
        }
    }

    private void BuildNodes(TreeViewItem treeNode, XmlNode parentElement)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode child in parentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (child.Name == "node" || child.Name == "reply")
            {
                XmlElement childElement = child as XmlElement;
                TreeViewItem childTreeNode = new TreeViewItem();
                string ID = child.SelectSingleNode(child.Name + "ID").InnerText;
                childTreeNode.Header = childElement.Name + ":" + ID;
                switch (child.Name)
                {
                    case "node":
                        childTreeNode.Selected += new RoutedEventHandler(Node_Selected);
                        break;
                    case "reply":
                        childTreeNode.Selected += new RoutedEventHandler(Reply_Selected);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }


                treeNode.Items.Add(childTreeNode);
                BuildNodes(childTreeNode, childElement);
            }
        }
    }

     private void Actor_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){}
     private void Dialog_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){}
     private void Node_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){}
     private void Reply_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){}
```

Comment: Do you want the Node selected to occur, but not Dialog and Actor selected?  Is that correct?

Comment: In my example, yes. If that would happen for Dialog, then only Dialog_Selected would happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event handler you can set e.Handled = true.  That will prevent the event from bubbling up the tree.

```
private void Node_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true; //this will prevent the event from bubbling up to parents;
   //Do the rest of the code here.
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for more information on RoutedEvents.  These include bubbling events which go up the tree and tunneling events which go down the tree.

Comment: That is so exactly the right answer. Work perfectly and I learnt something. Will check out reference. Thank you.